# How to update all indirect dependencies after fresh project creation

Tags: meteor, command-line-interface

So, ever since meteor unpinned package versions to the releases I've been experiencing this problem.

when I run `$ meteor create [project]`, cd into that project and then check it with `$ meteor update`

I get the following:

```
$ meteor update
This project is already at Meteor 1.4.0.1, the latest release.
Your top-level dependencies are at their latest compatible versions.

Newer versions of the following indirect dependencies are available:
 * autoupdate 1.2.11 (1.3.11 is available)    
 * caching-compiler 1.0.6 (1.1.6 is available)
 * ddp-client 1.2.9 (1.3.0 is available)      
 * ddp-server 1.2.10 (1.3.9 is available)     
 * http 1.1.8 (1.2.8 is available)            
 * templating 1.1.14 (1.2.13 is available)    
To update one or more of these packages, pass their names to `meteor
update`.
```

Which means then the next command is inevitably:

```
$ meteor update autoupdate caching-compiler ddp-client ddp-server http templating

Changes to your project's package version selections from updating package
versions:

autoupdate        upgraded from 1.2.11 to 1.3.11
caching-compiler  upgraded from 1.0.6 to 1.1.6
ddp-client        upgraded from 1.2.9 to 1.3.0
ddp-server        upgraded from 1.2.10 to 1.3.9
http              upgraded from 1.1.8 to 1.2.8
templating        upgraded from 1.1.14 to 1.2.13
```

And this is frankly annoying.

When I create a new project - I want everything to be the latest and greatest - *new*.  Now, I understand sometimes some people don't want that and I'm okay with that.  But for people like me, it sure would be nice to have a command `meteor update everything` - papa want's a brand new car!

Is anyone aware of such a command?  The [documentation](https://docs.meteor.com/commandline.html#meteorupdate) doesn't seam to have this command listed.

---

#### Edit:

Note, that this also doesn't work:

```
$ meteor update --packages-only
Your top-level dependencies are at their latest compatible versions.

Newer versions of the following indirect dependencies are available:
 * autoupdate 1.2.11 (1.3.11 is available)    
 * caching-compiler 1.0.6 (1.1.6 is available)
 * ddp-client 1.2.9 (1.3.0 is available)      
 * ddp-server 1.2.10 (1.3.9 is available)     
 * http 1.1.8 (1.2.8 is available)            
 * templating 1.1.14 (1.2.13 is available)    
To update one or more of these packages, pass their names to `meteor
update`.
```